# JavaEntity Bean defined but being passed as a class object

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0, javabeans

```
public Result addHouse() {
    House house = Form.form(House.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    house.save();
    return redirect(routes.Application.index());
}
```

// Above code calls the .save() method on the EntityBean to save it to the database - instead throwing error illegalArgument

```
import play.db.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
/**
 * Created by ctcmacadmin on 6/21/15.
 */
@Entity
public class House extends Model{

    @Id
    public String id;

    public String owner;
    public String address;
    public String postalCode;
}
```

// Above code defines the House object as an JPA Entity

```
[IllegalArgumentException: Was expecting an EntityBean but got a class model.House]
```

// Above is the resulting error from calling the addHouse() Method

Answer (score 1):

Have you included `@Table` annotation?
I encountered the same issue; it got resolved with `@Table` annotation.

Ex:-

```
@Table(name = "[your table name]")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the play framework, but I think the error message is clear:
It expects an instance where you have given a class.

As the only position of a class in your code is `Form.form(House.class)`:
I would guess that it expects something like `Form.form(House.findById(...))`.

Comment: The line that is throwining the error is 
house.save();

Comment: It would help if you would post the stacktrace of your exception.

Comment: [error] - play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Cannot invoke the action
[info] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Was expecting an EntityBean but got a class model.House
[info]  at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.checkEntityBean(DefaultServer.java:1576) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-4.6.2.jar:na]
[info]  at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1461) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-4.6.2.jar:na]
[info]  at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServer.save(DefaultServer.java:1454) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-4.6.2.jar:na]

Comment: You can edit your original question to include these infos - with some more lines of the stacktrace, starting at your `addHouse` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Ebean with play framework, and you are missing bean finder here. Take a look at the following link.

[sample bean model](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaEbean#using-model-superclass)